# How to use google's new reCAPTCHA "I am not a robot" in asp .net

Tags: asp.net, recaptcha

Hi I would like to use google's new reCAPTCHA in my website. Does anyone has working example in asp .net with codebehind implementation.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hi Tony you can find out detailed article with sample code here:
http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Google-New-reCaptcha-I-am-not-a-robot-using-asp-n